# Regular expression to find the beginning of a paragraph in Word

Tags: regex, ms-word, word-2016

I'm using Word 2016 and I need to delete some paragraphs, beginning or ending with known words.
For example, in the following text:

> ¶
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.¶
>
> Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua,¶
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea.¶
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut enim ad minim veniam, ...¶

Paragraphs starting with a given word/string work as expected (delete 1st and 4th paragraphs):

Find What: `"Lorem ipsum dolor *^13"` | 
Replace With: `""` | Wildcard: `On`

Paragraphs ending with a given word/string are not working (delete 2nd paragraph). Tried:

- `"^13* magna aliqua,^13"` ^10 = CR - deletes everything on the left, including previous paragraphs
- `"^10*magna aliqua,^13"` ^10 = LF - no changes

I've also tried some interesting examples on this site [http://word.mvps.org/.../usingwildcards.htm](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm) but didn't find the solution.

Is there any way of doing this without VBA?

Comment: you want something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/1) ?

Comment: Does that work with WinWord? Anyway, your example just removes the last words. I need to delete the whole paragraph.

Comment: you mean this whole line `Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua,¶` ?

Comment: yes, added these details in my question

Comment: try [this](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/3)

Comment: Pavneet, it's something like that but your code is written in php...

Answer (score 2):

> `"^13* magna aliqua,^13"` ^10 = CR - deletes everything on the left, including previous paragraphs

That's understandable, because the `*` matches any characters, including the CR, so the matched part extends from the first found CR over any paragraphs lain inbetween up to the one ending with `magna aliqua,`.

In order to not match other paragraph endings, we have to use something other than `*`:

```
[!^13]@ magna aliqua,^13
```

The `[!^13]` means "any character except CR", the `@` means "one or more occurrences of this".

Answer (score 0):

To delete all paragraphs beginning with 'Lorem', as per your example, you might use a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = ^13Lorem[!^13]{1,}
Replace = nothing
```

To delete all paragraphs ending with 'magna aliqua,', as per your example, you might use a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = [!^13]@magna aliqua,^13
Replace = nothing
```

You can't really combine these into a single Find/Replace that with find `either` - only one that will find both.